# Create a SEXP vector using fromList

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the [Data.Vector.SEXP](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.10/inline-r-0.8.0.1/Data-Vector-SEXP.html) module. I am a newbie in Haskell. 
Here is what I do and get:

```
> let x = Data.Vector.SEXP.fromList [2,3]

<interactive>:35:5:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (ElemRep s ty)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘x’ has the inferred type
      x :: forall s (ty :: Foreign.R.Type.SEXPTYPE).
           (ty
            Foreign.R.Constraints.:∈ '['Foreign.R.Type.Char,
                                       'Foreign.R.Type.Logical, 'Foreign.R.Type.Int,
                                       'Foreign.R.Type.Real, 'Foreign.R.Type.Complex,
                                       'Foreign.R.Type.String, 'Foreign.R.Type.Vector,
                                       'Foreign.R.Type.Expr, 'Foreign.R.Type.WeakRef,
                                       'Foreign.R.Type.Raw],
            Num (ElemRep s ty), Storable (ElemRep s ty),
            Data.Singletons.SingI ty) =>
           Data.Vector.SEXP.Vector s ty (ElemRep s ty)
```

I am lost. I'd like to have an example of a SEXP vector created from a list.

Comment: Try `:set -XFlexibleContexts` at the GHCi prompt.

Comment: @RowanBlush Thank you, it works. But then I can't print `x` (error when I type `x` at the prompt). Is it expected ?

Comment: Ah! Fool me once, GHC... Alec has the best answer down below.

Comment: @RowanBlush Alec's answer doesn't work, I already tried such things before posting my question. Is it possible to use `:set -XFlexibleContexts` in a module ?

Comment: I see, in a module I have to set `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead:

```
> let x = Data.Vector.SEXP.fromList ([2,3] :: [Int])
```

The problem is that in Haskell, number literals are overloaded, so `[2,3]` has type `Num a => [a]` instead of `[Int]`.

Comment: This gives ` Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’` and many other error messages.

Comment: I tried `[Int]` instead of `Int` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm what about `Int32`?

Comment: Not in scope. I also tried `[Double]`, this doesn"t work.

Comment: Try adding the import `import Data.Int (Int32)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way taken from the [HaskllR unittests](https://github.com/tweag/HaskellR/blob/master/inline-r/tests/vector.hs) is to specific a data type

```
import qualified Foreign.R as R
import qualified Data.Vector.SEXP as V

idVec :: V.Vector s 'R.Real Double -> V.Vector s 'R.Real Double
idVec = id
```

Then:

`let v = idVec $ V.fromList [-1.9,-0.1,-2.9]`

Comment: I can't enter your first two lines. Even when I add `let` before, I get a parse error at the second line.

Comment: Many errors such as ` Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘V.Vector’`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'll put the correct qualified imports for you

Comment: still an error after the imports: "Data constructor ‘R.Real’ cannot be used here
      (Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds)
"

Comment: I managed to define `idvec` after setting `:set -XDataKinds`.

Comment: try adding `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}` at the top

Comment: I'm in GHCI, so I set `:set -XDataKinds` and not `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}`. Now I can enter your code, but then I type `v` and I get something very strange. `fromList` appears in the console and GHCI is crashed.